# How do we use the generator with FsCheck?

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck

[This link](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck//TestData.html) explains the generator, but does not specify exactly how to use it.
I am not sure how to test the contents of the list generated by the generator.

I would like the following code.
(*forall* is an imaginary function.)

```
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

let isZero x = (x = 0)

let Zeros = Gen.constant 0 |> Gen.sample 0 100 

[<Property>]
let TestSample =
    forall isZero Zeros
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this can be confusing. It's simplest to define a custom type and then create a generator for it:

```ml
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

type Zero = MkZero of int

let isZero (MkZero x) = (x = 0)

type Arbs =

    // This is the generator for the Zero type.
    static member Zero() =
        MkZero 0
            |> Gen.constant
            |> Arb.fromGen

[<Property>]
let TestSample zeros =
    List.forall isZero zeros

[<assembly: Properties(
    Arbitrary = [| typeof<Arbs> |])>]
do ()
```

The `Zero` type has a generator that creates zero values. The `TestSample` property then confirms that every element of an arbitrary list of zeros is indeed zero. FsCheck will automatically generate lists of various sizes to confirm this. You can run with `Verbose = true` to see them if you want.

Since you want to use Xunit properties, you have to register the generator, as described [here](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck//RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-Xunit).

As the documentation [mentions](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck//TestData.html#Generator-examples), you shouldn't use `Gen.sample` when writing properties.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Thanks to you I was able to use Generator with FsCheck.